# If I purchase a game on another account, do I need to redownload it again?

Tags: ps4, psn

I logged into another account (whose primary PS4 is not mine) and downloaded some games. I then saw that they are locked when I am logged in from **my** PSN account, so I bought those games from Playstation store on my account.

Because I had already downloaded them on the other account, cancelled the download. The problem is that they are still locked.

My internet is pretty slow and I don't want to have to redownload them again. Is there a way to play them without deleting and re-downloading them?

Answer (score 2):

If you select download it should only download the license.

Like games that come with pre-order bonus, if you download them, ever noticed they are only a few KB downloads? This is because the items are already in the game, the download is just the license/activation.

So if you select to the-download it should only take two minutes at most to go threw your download then it'll finish.

Comment: Also maybe try to "Restore Licenses" option in settings while logged in as the user who bought the game(s).